# Mongo repository for Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-batch, spring-data, spring-data-document

Is there a Mongo-based job repository for Spring Batch?  If not, would I need to implement [`JobInstanceDao`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/JobInstanceDao.html) and its siblings?  Are there any examples or existing works that would help in this endeavor?

Comment: Great question, i'd be interested to find out too..

Comment: I would use SpringBatch over HSQL DB: more robust and proved solution. You want to share Mnogo DB with other project components?

Comment: @dma_k - i'd be willing to try the HSQL since it's got a good track record, but my other components use mongoDB and i like the document-oriented and javascript-powered capabilities

Comment: @dma_k I'd be willing to wager that writing queries based on the job execution params table would be significantly cleaner against a document database than a relational one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is a https://github.com/jbaruch/springbatch-over-mongodb project, it looks discontinued, but it might give you a better start

Answer (score 2):

I have a github project which enhanced JBaruch's Springbatch-over-mongodb to newer versions of

- Spring framework (4+)
- Spring-batch (3+)
- Mongo DB driver: 2.11.2

https://github.com/vfouzdar/springbatch-mongoDao

Though I have tested it and have a upgraded almost all of junits from JBaruch's project but it is still under BETA phase. If somebody is interested then s/he can give a try.